# How to plot a filled polygon on a map in cartopy

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

**Edited, adding suggestion from an answer**

I have a list of vertices in lat/lon that define corners of a polygon on a map. I would like to draw that polygon on a map using cartopy, where the edges are great circles. I've tried following the examples at https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.5/matplotlib/introductory_examples/02.polygon.html, but I can't get it to work. Here's what I have tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

map_proj = ccrs.Orthographic(central_latitude=0.0, central_longitude=80.0)
ax = plt.axes(projection=map_proj)

ax.set_global() # added following an answer to my question
ax.gridlines()

ax.coastlines(linewidth=0.5, color='k', resolution='50m')

lat_corners = np.array([-20.,  0., 50., 30.])
lon_corners = np.array([ 20., 90., 90., 30.]) + 15.0 # offset from gridline for clarity

poly_corners = np.zeros((len(lat_corners), 2), np.float64)
poly_corners[:,0] = lon_corners
poly_corners[:,1] = lat_corners

poly = mpatches.Polygon(poly_corners, closed=True, ec='r', fill=False, lw=1, fc=None, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.add_patch(poly)
```

[image: Output image]

Notice that the lines are not great circles, and there seem to be more than four vertices. I feel like this is such a simple thing to do there must be a way, but I can't figure that out from the cartopy documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is probably because Cartopy's default transform resolution is too low for this projection. You can work around this by forcing a higher resolution:

```
map_proj = ccrs.Orthographic(central_latitude=0.0, central_longitude=80.0)
map_proj._threshold /= 100.
...
```

This gives nice curved great circle arcs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a runnable code and output.
Credits go to: the asker, ImportanceOfBeingErnest, and ajdawson.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

map_proj = ccrs.Orthographic(central_latitude=0.0, central_longitude=80.0)

map_proj._threshold /= 100.  # the default values is bad, users need to set them manually

ax = plt.axes(projection=map_proj)

ax.set_global() # added following an answer to my question
ax.gridlines()

ax.coastlines(linewidth=0.5, color='k', resolution='50m')

lat_corners = np.array([-20.,  0., 50., 30.])
lon_corners = np.array([ 20., 90., 90., 30.]) + 15.0 # offset from gridline for clarity

poly_corners = np.zeros((len(lat_corners), 2), np.float64)
poly_corners[:,0] = lon_corners
poly_corners[:,1] = lat_corners

poly = mpatches.Polygon(poly_corners, closed=True, ec='r', fill=True, lw=1, fc="yellow", transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.add_patch(poly)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mind, that the example uses

```
ax.set_global()
```

Comment: Now I see the coastlines, but the polygon is still wrong (see my edited question)

Comment: Yes, apparently, the Polygon has not been implemented in cartopy. Why not use a rectangle instead?

Comment: I need to plot grid cells of circulation models defined on non-lat-lon grids, such as cubed sphere and icosahedral grids. They're not rectangles, even if some of them have four vertices.

Comment: In that case, can you increase the resolution of the polygon. I mean, in the extreme case you can provide a polygon with a point every 100km or so.

Comment: I guess I could do that, but that would involve me computing all the intermediate points, which involves reinventing the wheel (i.e., drawing great circles). Since the title of the example page said "Drawing a geodetic polygon", I had hoped that it would actually work for a polygon :-(

Comment: Would your polygon then be described by 4 great circles? In that case plotting those four edges of the polygon individually might be an option?

Comment: Correct, except that I need to draw a filled polygon. I didn't add the fill in the example because it didn't draw the polygon correctly to begin with.

Comment: I would suggest the following: You put everything that's discussed here inside the question; once that's done I would delete this answer, such that the question remains virgin and clear.